# Using selector in Swift 3 NotificationCenter observer

Tags: ios, selector, swift3

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: Selector(("uploaded")), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "uploaded"), object: nil)
```

I was writing name: "uploaded:" and xcode corrected it to the above code. The problem is when running the app i get unrecognized selector.

Any one know how to fix this to work with swift 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.update), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "uploaded"), object: nil)

func update() {
      // do what you want
   }
```

please note that "ViewController" is the class name where your function is

Comment: Or, rather than replacing `ViewController` with the class name, just omit the class name altogether and it will use the current class.

Answer (score 3):

Use the (identifier checking) `#selector` syntax:

Without parameter:

```
#selector(uploaded)
```

With parameter:

```
#selector(uploaded(_:))
```