# How to set NotificationCenter's observer when selector is a static method

Tags: swift, selector, nsnotificationcenter, observers, notificationcenter

```
func addObserver(_ observer: Any, selector aSelector: Selector, name aName: NSNotification.Name?, object anObject: Any?)
```

This function needs the observer to be some object but while setting **static methods** as the selector.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39984295/6536841) explains how to set selector and observer when the selector is an **instance method**.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We need set `YourClass.self` as the observer. In this way -

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(YourClass.self, selector: #selector(YourClass.yourStaticMethod), name: NSNotification.Name.BlahBlah, object: nil)
```